# How to change the width/height of the colorbar in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Does the pgfplots package have the option to adjust the width or height of the colorbar? For example, I want to make the colorbar in the following figure more narrow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    colormap/cool, 
    colorbar horizontal,
    colorbar style={
    at={(0,1.2)},
    anchor=north west,
    height=2cm,
    width=2cm,}
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=flat] {x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you answered you question yourself, just change `height` or `width` in your `colorbar style`, or maybe I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right key to use is `colorbar/width` to change the `width` of the `colorbar`. To change the `height` use `height` in the `colorbar style` options or `width` in conjunction with `colorbar horizontal`.

(I also did some minor improvements for the positioning of the `colorbar` which is now independent of the chosen `colorbar/width`.)

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/cool,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colorbar style={
            at={(0,1.0)},               % <-- (changed)
            anchor=below south west,    % <-- (changed)
            % change the width of the colorbar relative to the main `axis' environment
            width=0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width},
        },
        % because you are using `colorbar horizontal' the following key
        % now changes the `height' of the colorbar
        colorbar/width=2.5mm,
    ]
        \addplot3 [surf, shader=flat] {x+y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Interesting. Thus, `width` inside `colorbar style` and `colorbar/width` outside of it modify different internal variables?

Comment: I guess yes, but **only** when you are using `colorbar horizontal`.